# Django rest framework: 'create( )' NotImplementedError when making Http POST request

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework

When making a post request in Django I get the error that 'create()' has not been implemented when I did indeed implement it in my serializer file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from people.models import People

class PeopleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    favoriteCity = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return People.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.favoriteCity = validated_data.get(
                                'favoriteCity',instance.favoriteCity)
        instance.save()
        return instance()
```

Clearly the create method has been implemented and I don't understand why i'm getting a NotImplementedError

Comment: Could you paste the full traceback ?

Comment: Something is probably missing in your view. Are you using viewsets ? generic views?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In your serializer class inherit from ModelSerializer instead of Serializer class since the later doesn't call create() method implicitly.

```
class PeopleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

The above change would do your job!

Answer (score 3):

Please check your indentation, that 'create' function should be inside that Serializer class, as below example.

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=111)
    roll = serializers.IntegerField()
    city = serializers.CharField(max_length=722)

    def create(self,validated_data):
        return Student.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if the keys inside data exactly match model attributes when you try to create an object of a particular model using the model serializer

Answer (score -1):

Please check your indentation, that 'create' function should be within that Serializer class Hopefully it will work.

Comment: from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Student

class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name=serializers.CharField(max_length=555)
    age=serializers.CharField(max_length=555)
    city=serializers.CharField(max_length=555)

    def create(self,validated_data):
        return Student.objects.create(**validated_data)

Answer (score -1):

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Student

class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
name=serializers.CharField(max_length=555)
def create(self,validated_data):
return Student.objects.create(**validated_data)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC0ls.png)